# Bookdown Download for HTML single document

Tags: r, bookdown

I have a bookdown book with multiple output formats.
I want the user to be able to download the content in multiple formats. This works wonders with PDF, EPUB and so on. But it does not work with single file HTML `bookdown::html_document2` documents as they are rendered in the present working directory `.` and not the `_book` folder.

E.g., when I specify `bookdown::git_book: ...` it gets created in `_book`.

When I use `bookdown::pdf_book: ...` it also gets created in `_book`.

However, when I use `bookdown::html_document2: ...`, it gets created in `.`.

Setting `output_dir` for the single page document didn't work.

Do you know how to solve this?

## MWE

```yaml
## _bookdown.yml
book_filename: "The-book"
delete_merged_file: yes

## _output.yml
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: rmd
  config:
    download:
      - ["The-book.pdf", "PDF"]
      - ["The-book.html", "HTML"]
bookdown::html_document2:
  toc: true
bookdown::pdf_book:
  keep_tex: no
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
  latex_engine: xelatex
```

and then in `01-intro.Rmd`

```r
# Intro

This is a test
```

Comment: Interesting observation. I think you found a bug/inconsistency here. I recently exported into a single/long output format, yikes ... `bookdown::word_document2`, and set the `output_dir` in the `_bookdown.yml`. That worked. But trying it with `html_document2` fails (even when not activating the gitbook output). I am not sure that this is done deliberately, as one may run into issues in your output_dir, if the chosen output name would coincide with one of the chapter names (and associated html files).

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I'll wait a couple of days and if we dont get an answer/workaround I will raise an issue. I see the issue with with filename clashes, but I think this is a risk the users can decide for themselves to take :)

Comment: I have not had the time to test it, but the documentation https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html suggests that setting `split_by: "none"` results in a single html file for the book. I would add `self_contained: TRUE` and `split_bib: FALSE` to force everything into one output file. Conceptually, one should be able to have a "regular" gitbook with splits and a gitbook with the aforementioned settings in the yml controlling the options.

Answer (score 1):

I make book directly from a R script and this work for me:

```
bookdown::render_book(
  input         = "index.Rmd",
  output_format = "bookdown::html_document2",
  output_file   = "_book/The-book.html"),
  )
```

By making the book from R script you can start to have fun with name (like adding the date) and directory of the book, noting that if the directory is not `_book` you will need to create it before. With pdf output you can use `output_dir` to have the directory created for you, but it seems not to work and even conflict with output_file for `html_document2`. Ex:

```
## PDF report
bookdown::render_book(
  input = "index.Rmd",
  output_format = "bookdown::pdf_document2",
  output_file = paste0("Proceedings-pdf-", format(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"), ".pdf"),
  output_dir = "Proceedings"
)

## HTML
dir.create("Proceedings", showWarnings = F)
bookdown::render_book(
  input = "index.Rmd",
  output_format = "bookdown::html_document2",
  output_file = paste0("Proceedings/Proceedings-html-", format(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"), ".html"),
  )
```

Comment: I ended up creating a build script as well, which uses `rmarkdown::render_site` to render all specificed output formats and then `file.copy` to copy the single-file HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Quarto is able to produce stand-alone html files (https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#self-contained). E.g.

```
---
project:
  type: book

format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true 
---
```

Note that this currently does not work if you specify an output path ([see here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2266)).